# Spring batch - Item reader to know last record processed by reader

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

`ItemReader`  is reading from ever growing existing table everytime the job runs. I am looking for option within Spring batch to query only the new records every time the schedule job runs.

If I have 50000 records read, next schedule should start from 50001.

My thought is to persist the id of the last record read by ItemReader ( last of the whole reader output and not the last of each chunk ) in DB and use in subsequent job schedule. I will return the data sorted by id from main table.

How do I know the last record in the writer? Any ideas.

Comment: Batch processing is about fixed, finite datasets. An "ever growing existing table" is not a fixed data set. You need to make each job instance process a fixed data set, for example by passing a range of IDs as job parameters like suggested by "Ken Chan". The process indicator pattern is another way to address that (using a boolean column to mark processed records, and making the reader read only unprocessed records on each run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make it explicit by passing the ID range of the records (ie. `fromId` and `toId`) that are required to be processed as the job parameters when running a batch job. Then in the `ItemReader`, you can rely on this ID range to return the data to process.

And somehow persist the the latest ID that is already processed to the DB (e.g. by  using `JobExecutionListener` when a job finished) . When the next scheduled job triggers, find out the next ID that is not processed and then start another job instance with this next ID as the parameter.

Comment: You could create a `JobParametersIncrementer` for this purpose that would use the last id processed by the previous job execution to set the next id to use for the new job execution.